# How can you do time series forecasting in Tensorflow (or with other tools) where features of the label timestep are known?

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series

This is a question about a general approach rather than a specific coding problem. I'm trying to do time series forecasting with Tensorflow where features of the label timestep are known to the model.  E.g. a human trying to predict a variable a week from now would know things that are going to happen in the next week that will affect that variable. So a window of 20 timesteps where the label is the 20th timestep would look something like this:

- Timesteps 1-19 would each have a set of features plus the timeseries data
- Timestep 20 would have a set of features which are known, plus the timeseries label which is unknown

Is there a model that could handle this sort of data? I've gone through the Tensorflow [time series forecasting tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#linear_model), done a Coursera course on Tensorflow time series forecasting and searched elsewhere but I can't find anything. I'm fairly new to this so apologies for any imprecise language.

Answer (score 1):

I once tried to do this kind of TS problem by stacking a multivariate model and another machine learning model. My idea was that I use the normal TS model's output, add it as another feature in the other model that only takes the last time step's info as input. But it is complicated and might overfit a lot even if I carefully regularized the second model. The idea is that I use step 1 to window_size - 1 info to predict a rough output at step window_size, then use the info at step window_size to reduce the residual between my TS model output and the actual label; But I don't think this approach is theoretically correct and the result might be worse than using a TS model without feeding the target step's info.

I don't think tensorflow have any API for your problem because this type of problem is not a normal TS problem. Usually people would just treat this kind of problem as a regression or classification problem.

I am not an expert on this problem as well, but I just happened to attempt to solve the exact problem so this is just my personal experience...